# IsolatedStorage settings file not created by the time they are first accessed

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, reference, isolatedstorage

i tried to do smth like that:

```
private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
    {
        var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        if (!settings.Contains("init"))
        {
            createStorage();
        }
     }
 public void createStorage()
    {
        var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        settings.Add("x", "randomtext");
        settings.Add("init", true);
    }
```

then i tried to do reference a variable to the isolated storage in the class:

```
public string x = (string)IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["x"];
```

but it seems, that application_launching is loaded after the class-variables, so i get a keyNotFound-exception.

how can i handle this? would erase 2 methods and when the app crashes, data is stored.
also, the app_launching process would be accelerated, because of it.

so, how could i handle this?

thanks
roqstr

Comment: .. what? I don't understand. Can you use real code instead of psuedocode and reword your question?

Answer (score 3):

Put the isolated storage settings check in the constructor... not the 'application launching event':

```
IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    createStorage();
}

public void createStorage()
{
    if (!settings.Contains("init"))
    {
        settings.Add("x", "randomtext");
        settings.Add("init", true);
    }
    settings.Save();      
}
```

Comment: i putted it into the constructor of app.xaml.cs, but i still get an exception that the key wasn't found

Comment: What does your source look like now?

Comment: `public App()
        {
    MessageBox.Show("constructor");
            createStorage();
}`

it doesn't even show the messagebox, the first thing it notices is the keyNotFoundException inside the class at 
`public string x = (string)IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["x"];
`

Comment: It sounds like `settings` is not getting initialized. Did you move `IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;` to either the constuctor or on declaration?

Comment: `public void createStorage()
        {
            var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
            if (!settings.Contains("init"))
            {
                settings.Add("x", "randomtext");
                settings.Add("init", true);}
`
there it is

Comment: I guess I missed it before but you appear to be working in App.xaml.cs. It is possible to use App.xaml.cs to handle IsolatedStorageSettings, but it would be easier for you to work in a PhoneApplicationPage first. It appears you called a message box within App.xaml.cs: `public App() { MessageBox.Show("constructor")`.  Make sure you are working on a PhoneApplicationPage.

Comment: OK, but i need the variables in more than 1 application page, how should i handle this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8456/discussion-between-impliciter-and-roqstr)